# IDE for mongodb for Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ide

Previously I was using **MongoDB** with the help of ***MobgoVUE*** on Windows 7, but now i switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu and am facing problem to work efficiently on mongodb by commands.

Can anyone help me suggest any IDE for MongoDB in Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Try Robomongo. It's free and open source. 
http://robomongo.org/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

Personally, I think that UMongo (formerly JMongoBrowser) seems to be the best option for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Two good options:

RockMongo (php)

GenghisApp (php/ruby)

Also start learning to use the Mongo Shell - better than any graphical ide. Go to mongodb.org and click on try the shell.

Comment: RockMongo is no longer maintained and is falling behind on a lot of features the later versions of MongoDB are getting, fact is it ain't that good anymore and I would recommend trying to move away from it a bit